# creating object and passing as a parameter for web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services

I have problem in passing object as parameter in webservice

My web service and presentation layer share same entity definition

It was working fine so far, but when i updated service reference and tried to build it,
it is throwing errors,

```
'Competition' is an ambiguous reference between 'Entity.BusinessEntities.Competition' 
and 'presentation.ServiceReference.Competition'
```

So i changed it to

`Entity.BusinessEntities.Competition=new Entity.BusinessEntities.Competition()` instead of 
`Competition= new Competition()`

But the webservice is not accepting that object !!

```
Service.CreateCompetition(Competition);
```

It says

```
 Cannot implicitly convert type 'Entity.BusinessEntities.Competition' to 
'presentation.ServiceReference.Competition'
```

Comment: do you have same named object in client side?

Comment: in the client side I am using the same entity definition and it is the same object as that of the one defined in service

Comment: Did you create the service reference somthat it uses the already existing types (advanced tab)? Seems that the data contracts have been recreated in the client project leading to a, mismatch between the entity classes you want to use and the client classes that the service reference expects.

Comment: Yeah the same datacontract and datamembers are used in both